# Show warning icon on the azure devops work item field

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

We are developing an azure devops custom extension for boards, where we need to make some field as required based on some condition. We can display an error message and disable the save button, but **how to show red color icon on that field**??

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you needs to show red color icon on your custom field.

You could assign red color to a tag which can display an error message or just be a red color icon as the linked capture shows:

[Assign a color to a tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONq5V.png)

The following steps are:

1.Before setting tag colors, add tags to work items that you want to highlight with color that circled in red in the linked capture.

[add tags to work items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DT4c9.png)

2.From the Settings dialog, choose Tag colors and then choose the "+" plus icon to add a tag color. Then, name the tag as "!" and select the red color.

3.When done with your changes, choose Save.

Then you could show red color icon on your custom field.